# Append Python returns instead of overwriting

Tags: python, function, return

I'm teaching myself Python and writing a simple GPA calculator. I have very little programming experience prior other than a college Java course, so bear with my code.

The premise is, the code will ask if you want to add a course to the list. If you do, it runs a function asking you the class name. Every time you add a class it'll ask if you want to add another. If you don't, it'll spit out a list of the classes you've added and then ask you to enter in the grades. I didn't get the grading part done yet. I don't think that will be too hard.

The problem is you can add a bunch of classes and it will only spit out the last one you entered. I'm assuming the issue is in askAgain(): classList = addClasses() because it keeps overwriting, but I'm not sure how to avoid a global variable (since they're bad?) and still keep this from overwriting itself. I seem to draw a blank when trying to figure out how to call something once to intialize it and not run it again. I've also read that conditional variables are bad, so I'm not sure what's best practice here. thanks

```
def main():
    askAgain()
    return 0


def askAgain():

    while True:
        addOrNot = raw_input("Add a class? [y/n]: ")
        if addOrNot == "Y" or addOrNot == "y":
            classList = addClasses() #This is probably where my issue is.
        else:
            try:
                editClassGradeSelection = mainMenu(classList)
                addGrades(editClassGradeSelection, classList)
            except:
                print("Hey you didn't add any classes yet.")    

def addClasses():
    try:
        if classList in locals():
            print("debug msg - classList exists")
    except:
        classList = []

    classList.append(raw_input("Add class to the list: "))
    return classList


def mainMenu(classList):
        print("Here are the classes you've added: ")
        counter = 0
        for classes in classList:
            print((str(counter+1)) + ". " + (str(classList[counter])) + "\n")
            counter = counter + 1
        while True:
            editGrade = raw_input("Enter the number for the class grade to edit: ")
            if int(editGrade) > len(classList) or int(editGrade) < 1:
                print("Enter a proper number in the range listed.")
            else:
                break

        return editGrade


def addGrades(editClassGradeSelection, classList):
    print("debug stuff for now: ")
    print((str(editClassGradeSelection)))
    print((str(classList[:])))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Playing with `locals` like that is a bad idea. Why not create `classlist` in `main` and pass it as an argument?

Answer (score 0):

Although this snippet makes sure `classlist` is defined:

```
try:
    if classList in locals():
        print("debug msg - classList exists")
except:
    classList = []
```

`classlist` is a local variable, hence everytime you run that function, `classlist` will be `[]`, which probably explains why you can't ever display more than one. The `classlist` you assign it to gets reassigned to the one element of `classlist` (`addClasses` scope) every time this line is called:

```
        classList = addClasses() #This is probably where my issue is.
```

Comment: That might be it. the debug message never runs either. If I'm returning a value, does whatever else I did in that function get erased from memory when the function is done running?

Comment: Ah, yes, I had to read it 5 times to understand. Not your fault. I guess it gets "wiped" every time then, so it will never exist the next time it runs, thus making it a clean slate.

Comment: `classList` in addClasses() is a local and create every time you call `classList=addClasses()`. Try `addClass(classList)` instead. Look at `mainMenu(classList)` function.